# Setting selected item in C# Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I've looked up this question everywhere yet could not find an answer. I have a combobox of enum values that's supposed to get its initial value from a class property. Keep in mind that it's NOT databound to the property. When I set the class property using the current selected item, there is no problem, yet when I try to set the initial value, the combobox is just blank.

I've debugged it and it seems like SelectedItem is being set properly, yet it's not visually updating the current item. Here's my code for populating the combobox:

```
foreach(Gender gender in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender)))
{
    genderComboBox.Items.Add(gender);
}
```

And I set it with this:

```
genderComboBox.SelectedItem = person.Gender;
```

I've also tried doing this before:

```
genderComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender));
```

Nothing works. I also tried converting the enum property to an int and using that to set the SelectedIndex. If I add breakpoints and check the values, everything seems like it should work, but it doesn't. I'm really confused by this.

Comment: That's strange because I have no problem with that code.

Comment: Same for me. This code works fine. I believe that the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Steve you're right, it works perfectly.

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find a solution online. It seems that the code is fine for everyone except for me. Might it have something to do with the combobox being inside a UserControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seemed to have figured it out.

The default value for `SelectedItem` is `Gender.Male`, the same as the default value for `person.Gender`. Since `SelectedItem` already equaled `Gender.Male`, it didn't visually update the control and left it blank. When I set `SelectedItem` to `null`, and then set it to the initial value, it suddenly worked.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "The default value for `SelectedItem` is `Gender.Male`"? `SelectedItem` is of type `object` and its default value is `null`. I cannot set another default value in the properties window than `(none)`.

Comment: When I set the `DataSource` property of the combobox, it automatically selects the first enum value as the `SelectedItem`. It doesn't make sense, but that's what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a test using your code with a little difference. It runs with no problem. Instead of taking the value from a person's property `Gender`, I am assigning a `Gender` constant directly:

```
genderComboBox.SelectedItem = Gender.Male;
```

This lets me assume that the property `person.Gender` does not have a valid `Gender` value. Set a breakpoint to the line `genderComboBox.SelectedItem = person.Gender;` and watch the value of `person.Gender`. Is it correct?

Note: If you declared `Gender` like this:

```
enum Gender
{
    Male = 1
    Female =2
}
```

... then the default value of `Gender` `0` is not a valid `Gender` value. Either add a value `None = 0` to the `enum` or initialize the property in `person` to a valid value.

Comment: Yes, when I add a breakpoint and check the value of `person.Gender`, I find a valid property. Everything seems valid when I debug it, yet it acts very strangely anyway.